# Matrix Input from file separated by comma in C into 2D

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I'm currently taking matrix input from file into a 2D array. Given like,

- 2,3,4

  1,2,3

  4,5,6
- 3,5,6,3,1

  2,3,6,7,8

  8,7,6,5,4

  3,4,6,7,8

The size of the matrix can vary. I'm able to do this for a 3*3 matrix with my code(given below). What change should I make so that I can input matrix of any size, like 7*7 or 5*5 ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXB 32
#define MAXL 18
#define MAXD 3

int main(void)
{
int i = 0,temp,n,m,j=0;
int numlines = 0;
char buf[MAXB] = {0},c;
char lines[MAXL][MAXD];

FILE *fp = fopen("num.txt", "r");

if (fp == 0)
{
   fprintf(stderr, "failed to open inputs/control.txt\n");
   return 1;
}

while (i < MAXL && fgets (buf, MAXB - 1, fp))
{
    if (sscanf (buf, "%hhd, %hhd, %hhd", &lines[i][0], &lines[i][1], &lines[i][2]) == 3)

        i++;
}

fclose(fp);

numlines = i;

for (i = 0; i < numlines; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < MAXD; j++)
        printf (" line[%2d][%2d] : %hhd\n", i, j, lines[i][j]);

printf ("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the `#define MAXD 3` to a bigger number? Maybe the code just works but is clamped to 3 due to hardcoded size.

Comment: @Shark Yes, this is for a 3*3 matrix. Hence, MAXD is 3. Since I want various size of inputs like 5*5 or 9*9 which is totally user defined, inside the text file, this method does not work for me.

Comment: Dynamically allocate `char** lines` which would be the equivallent of `lines[rows][columns]`

Comment: @Shark Yes, I can do that, but how do I do that in this case where I don't know the number of elements in a row ? Won't it be an infinite loop ?

Comment: Didn't you just say `"Since I want various size of inputs like 5*5 or 9*9 which is totally user defined, inside the text file"` ? So, you do know the number of elements before you even start reading them.

Comment: @Shark I'm sorry for the confusion, the size of the matrix will vary. Hence what kind of changes should I make.

Comment: Avoid reading 3 numbers per row as rows won't be limited to 3 ? ... Like, this whole line `if (sscanf (buf, "%hhd, %hhd, %hhd", &lines[i][0], &lines[i][1], &lines[i][2]) == 3)` needs to be rewritten. And a few others as well.

Comment: Are all the matrices square ?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your `while` loop with something simple like this:

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%hhd", &lines[i][k]) > 0) {

    //check to see if the next character is a comma
    fscanf(fp, "%c", &check);

    //if it is a comma, go to the next char, else go to the next line
    if (check == ',') {k++;} else {i++; k=0;}

}
```

Of course you will have to change some of your constants like `MAXD` for larger dimensions.

Also, for this code you need to create an integer `k` and a character `check` before the while loop.

Comment: So, my code should be..
     

    while (fscanf(fp, "%hhd", &lines[i][k]) > 0) {

    scanf("%d",&line[i][k]);

          //check to see if the next character is a comma

        fscanf(fp, "%c", &check);

        //if it is a comma, go to the next char, else go to the next line

        if (check == ',') {k++;} else {i++; k=0;}

     }

Comment: 1) Replace your `while` loop with what I wrote. 2) Change your `MAXD` value to something larger. 3) add `int k=0;` to your first line after `int main(void)`. 4) Also add `char check;`. It should work.

Comment: Okay, the problem here is when I change the MAXD to something big, the number of columns also increase. say like MAXD=50. I have values in 4th row from line[3][0] to line[3][49]. Hence I think I need the exact number of columns. How do I do that ?

Comment: A simple solution would be to use `scanf` to ask the user the expected number of columns. Then initialize the array to the correct size. But thats usually not recommended.

The question is, do you really need the array to be of the exact size? If you want to print the array nicely, you could loop through the correct number of elements (e.g for 8x8 matrix, just loop 8 times each row and ignore the rest). 

To do that, you can create a new `int` and assign it the value of `k` in the `while.. ` loop's `else.. ` condition (before `k` is set to `0`).